# Can't build crc32c

Tags: build, centos, kernel, yum, crc32

It's a C implementation.

Firstly, while building, it exits with error: "warning: linux/if_alg.h: No such file or directory". Then I run `yum install kernel-devel-{version}`, but it doesn't work.

Secondly when I copy the file from another PC, the error becomes "error: ‘AF_ALG’ undeclared (first use in this function)".

I have no idea to solve this issue. Please help me.

And here is my PC's info:
`CPU:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5335  @ 2.00GHz`

OS: `CentOS 6.5`

Kernel-release: 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: Absolutely do not ever just randomly copy system header files (or libraries or binaries) from one machine and plunk them down in the normal system locations on another machine. That is never the right answer. What do you mean when you said " I run yum install kernel-devel-{version}, but it doesn't work"? What didn't work? The yum install? The build after that?

Comment: I mean though I hava run this commend, but the error is still there.

Comment: Did yum install something? Did yum tell you the package was already installed? That file also looks like it might be a fairly new addition to the kernel, far newer than the 2.6.32 version you have installed.